# Bootstrap 3 and Jquery Validation plugin: Does not work in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use jquery validation plugin with Bootstrap 3 to validate my input fields. However, it seems that it does not work in IE8. Is there a fix for this? [My live demo.](http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/contact.php)

My code:

```
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control input-lg" tabindex="1">
```

Jquery:

```
<script>

$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: {
            required : true
        },
        lastName: {
            required : true
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I had to revert to an older version of Jquery (v 1.8.3).